# How to execute a riscv64 binary on qemu-system-riscv64?

Tags: linux, qemu, emulator, riscv

I want to run a simple hello world program compiled for riscv64 machine on qemu. I have `qemu-system-riscv64` and the `riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc` toolchain installed.

Is there sequence of command line steps one can follow to run a simple program? I have Ubuntu machine.

OTOH this page https://danielmangum.com/posts/risc-v-bytes-qemu-gdb/ suggested that the binary should be able to execute automatically as long as the emulator is registered with `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` but I don't have it registered. How do we register it such that it becomes straightforward to run binaries.

Comment: Do you also have `qemu-user` and `qemu-user-static` installed? I was able to run the binary with the help of this article, https://azeria-labs.com/arm-on-x86-qemu-user/